# MediaCodec Encoded video has green bar at bottom and chrominance screwed up

Tags: android, encoding, opengl-es, android-mediacodec, grafika

I started a project from [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) and modified it. I've got a framework (not too different from the original) which captures a preview from the `Camera` and continuously encodes it to a video at the same time both at different resolutions.

`MediaCodec` (for encoding) is configured to use `COLOR_FormatSurface` in order for us to be able to render to the Surface queried using `getInputSurface()` using GLES.

The media format is set to MIME Type `video/avc`

**For most phones, this setup works perfectly.**

But for a few phones, the encoded video has the chrominance values slightly skewed and a green bar at the bottom.

Currently the encoder surface is of 640x360 resolution.
EGLConfig choosen to render to the surface supports 32 bit RGBA format.

The **preview is perfect** in all phones.

So I am assuming there's some thing wrong with the encoder parameters either on the application side or the OS framework side.

It's happening on Android 4.4. - Not sure, if it's reproducible on 5.*.

[image: ![Green bar image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnsJh.jpg)

Comment: That sure looks like a color format problem, which shouldn't be happening when encoding from a Surface. Are you able to try other resolutions? I'm curious if the codec on these devices has a bug at that resolution. Do you know if all affected devices have the same video encoder chip? (You can usually tell by looking at logcat -- there's usually some hardware-specific babbling.)

Comment: Usually, the preview resolution and the encoding resolution are different. Is `640x360` the encoding resolution also? Are you encoding `1080p`? If so, then I think your issue is due to alignment vertically. The encoder may be reading __1088__ instead of __1080__. If so, the camera output should be aligned similarly.

Comment: The preview is 720p. It doesn't matter. Because I'm rendering it as a texture (Using OpenGLES) to the encoder surface. @fadden has already pointed out the issue. Looks like the codec issue. I'm now using a Surface with height as the next multiple of 16.

Comment: @Ganesh: Sorry, I think I didn't explain the question correctly.
Camera preview: 720p,  

Device Preview resolution: Device resolution,  

Encoder resolution: 360p,  
The thing is youtube livestreaming API supports only these resolutions:
[Livestreaming supported resolutions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702?hl=en)

Should I just use height 368 instead of 360?
The problem with that is the aspect ratio is spoiled and youtube will add a bit of blanking on either side.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I've added an answer, because of word limit in comments. Check it out

Comment: @fadden: Are you aware of any fix/workaround for this. I want to encode at `1080`, but I am getting same issue on a MediaTek chipset device. I have tried encoding at `1072`, and that seems fine. But I don't want to go with this solution, for several reasons - 1) Non standard resolution, 2) How to decide which device encodes at `1080` and which of them require `1072`, 3) Other issues may crop up (exporting at `1088` fixed this issue, but added other issues)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You're not the only one having MediaTek issues (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891420/). Have you checked the MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel to confirm that the device advertises support for 1080p? Many devices have a "secret" multiple-of-16 requirement but correctly handle 1080 anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I'll answer that for myself just in case anyone else find it useful.

Apparently the issue only occurs on a few select chipsets such as `MediaTek` ones, which don't support **non multiple of 16** resolutions. In my case it was 640x360 (where height is a multiple of 8). To partially solve it, I added a check in the App code, if the encoder is *Omx.mtk*, then reconfigure the encoder with width/height as the `next multiple of 16`, which comes out to be 640x368 in my case (closest to the requirement i.e. 360p).

For me, YouTube player adds a slight blanking on either side, which is the best we can do with those encoders.

In case you don't have dependency on any third party APIs/players etc